# How to build a newer version of u-boot for the cpu exynos 5250 of the Google / Samsung ARM chromebook "SNOW" model XE303C12

Tags: embedded, arm, u-boot, chrome-book, chrome-os

I'm trying to build a recent copy of the u-boot loader to use with my old google-samsung ARM chromebook snow. Until now I've used the copy created by the company virtualopensystems,located here :

http://www.virtualopensystems.com/en/solutions/guides/kvm-on-chromebook/

you can read what they say here :

> To be able to run KVM on ARM platforms, the kernel has to be booted in
> hypervisor mode. Because of this relatively recent requirement (due to
> the introduction of the virtualization extensions), up until now all
> booting methods would boot the kernel in the standard Supervisor mode.
> For the ARM Chromebook the default boot procedure doesn't allow us to
> boot in hypervisor mode. Although the laptop's boot mechanism is based
> on the frequently used u-boot, the binary is located in RO memory.
> Fortunately, a chained u-boot mechanism can be used (i.e. starting
> another u-boot after the original). We can then enter hypervisor mode
> from the our custom iteration of u-boot and subsequently load our
> kernel and userspace. Checkout the needed u-boot code:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/virtualopensystems/u-boot.git 
$ cd u-boot 
$ ./scripts/build.sh
```

They written that guide on 2013 ! A long time ago. Its not good anymore today. At least for what I'm trying to achieve. Infact on the guide they used the kernel 3.13. What I'm trying to do now is to recompile a more recent kernel (5.4 I think is the better one) to enable KVM again on my ARM chromebook. After a lot of experiments I've reached the conclusion that the errors that I'm getting may be are caused by the old u-boot file and I would like to use a fresh version of the same. So,this is what I did :

```
git clone https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot 
make smdk5250_defconfig 
Makefile:40: *** missing operator.  Stop.
```

I don't now what to do at this point. Furthermore,in this website :

https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/architectures-and-processors-blog/posts/virtualization-on-the-chromebook-using-kvm-tool

at some point,I read :

> To enable access to the virtualization extensions, we need to boot the
> Chromebook into what is known as Hyp Mode (more information on Hyp
> Mode can be found at Chapter 27 of the Cortex-A Series Programmer’s
> Guide.  To be able to enter Hyp Mode, we need to use a secondary
> bootloader as the Chromebook’s bootloader doesn’t support entering
> this higher privileged run level.
> To do this we will build a version of u-boot. Rather than use
> upstream’s u-boot source tree, we will use Virtual Open Systems’ tree
> as they have integrated many of the fixes needed to fully support Hyp
> mode, and also have an easy to use script for building u-boot.

I'm interested to know which kind of fixes he is talking about,because I suspect that if I compile a new u-boot file,I will need to patch it to be able to enter Hyp Mode. I need to know how to patch it. Thanks to everyone for the help.